# I'd like to filter out objects which do not have an ext key on them

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

How can I remove objects which do not have an `ext` key? I want to take pictures, but there is a problem because some objects do not have a picture. I'm confused about filtering. Can it be done with reduce or filter?

```json
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "filename": "1647706792183",
      "ext": ".png",
      "w": 300,
      "h": 450,
      "tn_w": 166,
      "tn_h": 250,
      "tim": 1664328637690788,
      "time": 1664328637,
      "md5": "Omk9VtmPOD1U38U1OOAP/w==",
      "fsize": 200271,
      "resto": 0,
      "country": "DK",
      "bumplimit": 0,
      "imagelimit": 0,
      "semantic_url": "f1-relentless-formula-one-general-all-smiles",
      "replies": 378,
      "images": 155,
      "unique_ips": 102,
      "tail_size": 50
    },
    {
      "now": "09/27/22(Tue)21:31:17",
      "name": "Anonymous",
      "resto": 123946553,
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I want to delete non ext keys

Comment: Rather than remove all properties except `ext`, why not only extract that property?

Comment: You should add what your expected output should look like because it's not clear from your question.

Comment: The output will be like this
 ``{
  "posts": [
    {
      "filename": "1647706792183",
      "ext": ".png",
......
    }
] 
}``

Comment: It will delete objects that are not ext as keys.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the expected output and any clarifications asked for.

Comment: I think you're saying "I'd like to filter out objects which do not have an `ext` key on them."

Comment: yes i want to say that sorry my english is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter` to run a function that returns true/false for each item of your data.

```js
const data = { posts: [ .... ] };

const postsWithExt = data.posts.filter(post => post.ext !== undefined);
```

If you want to filter falsy values for `.ext` then use

```
posts.filter(post => !post.ext)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just filter your `posts` array where the `ext` property exists.

e.g.

```js
const data = {
  "posts": [{
      "filename": "1647706792183",
      "ext": ".png",
      "w": 300,
      "h": 450,
      "tn_w": 166,
      "tn_h": 250,
      "tim": 1664328637690788,
      "time": 1664328637,
      "md5": "Omk9VtmPOD1U38U1OOAP/w==",
      "fsize": 200271,
      "resto": 0,
      "country": "DK",
      "bumplimit": 0,
      "imagelimit": 0,
      "semantic_url": "f1-relentless-formula-one-general-all-smiles",
      "replies": 378,
      "images": 155,
      "unique_ips": 102,
      "tail_size": 50
    },
    {
      "now": "09/27/22(Tue)21:31:17",
      "name": "Anonymous",
      "resto": 123946553,
    }
  ]
};

const result = data.posts.filter(x => x.ext);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @JoeyCiechanowicz Please don't use comments to add meta-commentary about downvoting. Also, downvoting is anonymous and **does not require commenting**; see the Meta FAQ [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436)